# Flag as duplicate popup lost under header

Tags: bug, flags, duplicate-questions

When trying to flag a question as a duplicate, I moved the popup window out of the way to grab the link from the accepted answer.  However, I moved it too high and could not move it back later because it was under the floating header.

[image: screenshot]